# Index outside of array

Tags: c#, arrays

So I am learning the basics of arrays using `C#` and my goal was to write a program that reverses an array. Here is how it looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] nums = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
        int[] reversed = new int[nums.Length];

        for (int i = nums.Length - 1; i<=nums.Length; i--) {
            reversed[i] = nums[i];
            Console.WriteLine(reversed[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, but it gives me this error:

> Run-time exception (line 12): Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> > [System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the
> >     array.]    at Program.Main() :line 12

Can someone please explain to me how did I overflow the bounds of the array and how that can be evaded. Isn't that the whole point of creating a new array and filling it?

Comment: Should be : for (int i = nums.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)

Comment: Walk though this in the debugger and watch the value of `i`

Comment: You are going to keep on asking questions like this until you learn to debug your own programs. This is the single biggest skill missing from novice programmers. You should make it your goal to acquire that skill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your code by simply rewriting your `for` loop as follows:

```
for (int i = nums.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
```

Since you are starting from `nums.Length - 1` (the last value of the array) and decreasing `i` after each iteration, you want to stop the loop when the index `0` (the first value of the array) is finally reached.

Alternatively, you can also proceed with a simpler approach that implies the usage of the [Enumerable.Reverse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497(v=vs.110).aspx) method, as follows:

```
int[] nums = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
int[] reversed = nums.Reverse().ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < reversed.Length; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine(reversed[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop condition is incorrect:

```
i<=nums.Length
```

This means that the loop will continue as long as i is less than `nums.Length`. Since you start off with `i = nums.Length - 1` and decrement `i` each time, `i` will always be less than `nums.Length`, so the loop theoretically will loop until `i` reaches the smallest value of `int`. However, when `i = -1`, and you try to access the array, an `IndexOutOfRangeException` occurs.

To make it stop when `i` is 0, change the condition to:

```
i > -1 // or i >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by using the built in Array class that will reverse your array without using any loop in just one line of code

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] nums = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
        Array.Reverse(nums); // reverse the Array

        foreach(int num in nums)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(num) // print reversed array
        }

    }
}
```